# Как часто стоит просчитывать путь от мобов к игроку? Поделитесь идеями

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр

> http://smartcook.info/testgame/test2.html

Поиск пути осуществляется через алгоритм А*
Представьте есть персонаж который бегает по плоскости, вот все эти мобики должны искать его или другие возможные цели, как часто стоит просчитывать путь к игроку, потому как ресурсозатратно.
Поделитесь идеями как стоит строить путь к игроку.

Comment: Что за алгоритм `А*`?

Comment: @NickVolynkin https:// en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

Comment: @php5engineer: спасибо. Оказывается, я его однажды даже сам реализовал в игре, только не знал названия.

Comment: На чем основано утверждение, что это ресурсозатратно и на сколько по вашему? JavaScript очень быстро считает и очень плохо рисует. Вполне вероятно, вы раньше упретесь в лимит рендера, чем в лимит расчетов. В любом случае постарайтесь сделать так, что бы этот момент можно было регулировать настройками и сначала протестируйте.

Comment: Если у вас есть другой вопрос, отличный от "Как часто стоит просчитывать путь от мобов к игроку?" то задавайте его пожалуйста отдельно.

Comment: Не нужно править исходный вопрос, задавайте новые. Этот я вернул к исходному состоянию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда-то писал игру вроде пакмана, поделюсь соображениями.

Максимальная частота пересчета ограничена тем, насколько часто мобы могут поворачивать. Насколько я понимаю, пока они идут из одной клетки в другую, смена марштута невозможна. Значит, пересчитывать путь нужно не чаще, чем тогда, когда моб полностью пришел в клетку, т.е. находится в её центре.

Максимальная частота также ограничена производительностью устройства, как верно отметил php5engineer в соседнем ответе.

Минимальная частота пересчета задает «агрессивность» мобов и определяет геймплей. Это может быть, например:

- На каждой клетке — очень злой преследователь
- На каждой 10й клетке — довольно-таки инертный преследователь, как бык в корриде.
- На каждой 5й и только если персонаж игрока находится в радиусе R клеток.
- Раз в 2 секунды вне зависимости от скорости моба

Answer (score 1):

> как часто стоит просчитывать путь к игроку, потому как ресурсозатратно

До полного исчерпания этих ресурсов?
Или до определенного процента. Например, не более 70% CPU.
Или по времени - не более 1/24 секунды.

Но это всё общие советы. Как это делается на JavaScript, описано [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Anatomy)

Answer (score 1):

Лови две сносные идеи:

1) Если поле небольшое, стенки во время игры не создаются и мобы респаунятся в одной точке можно вообще всего 1 раз при загрузке просчитать путь в каждую точку поля.

Тогда в худшем случае придется искать маленький путь до следующего пути в списке.

2) Можно гонять их по графу из вейпоинтов тем же А*, а А* для реального поля просчитывать только если расстояние до игрока критически уменьшилось.

Comment: стенки создаются, игрок может строить баррикады, как в warcraft в многочисленных ТД  где мобики спаунились и шли в определенную точку там умирали

Comment: Ну тогда по второму пункту. ["A* over navmesh"](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5013/how-does-pathfinding-in-rts-games-work), как во всех RTS все и делают.